# How to customize the toolbar in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs, customization

Is it still impossible to customize the toolbar with extra buttons? Specifically, I'd like to add the strikethrough one (especially with how horrendous the keystroke for it is), but a general solution would be better.

I know there used to be at least one script for this, but the one I've found is clearly outdated (Ive looked at the source code and there's no way it'd work with GDocs' current layout).

I also know that I can create scripts to add extra menus, but that is not what I'm looking for.

I am open to any solution that allows me to add a button to the toolbar, even if it's a lead on how to write a greasemonkey script for that.

Answer (score 7):

From [Scott Esser](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-change-my-Google-Docs-toolbar-to-one-more-similar-to-the-ribbons-used-by-current-versions-of-Microsoft-Word)  Nov 5, 2016 (and slightly out  of context!):

> The only way to change the toolbars in Google’s office products - Docs, Sheets, and Slides - is to convince Google

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to edit the Google Docs toolbar, only very basically – by tweaking the CSS. This Chrome extension can inject custom CSS into any page: [User CSS - Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-css/okpjlejfhacmgjkmknjhadmkdbcldfcb?hl=en)

I used it to hide some of the buttons I rarely use, so I can make my browser window smaller w/out forcing the buttons on the right into the "overflow menu."

Idk if it's possible to ADD a button, but removing them is quite easy.

Google Sheets Default Toolbar (w/the overflow menu open):

[image: Google Sheets Default Toolbar]

My "Short" Toolbar:

[image: Google Sheets Customized (Short) Toolbar]

Here's the CSS I used to do it:

```
#t-num-fmt-currency,
#t-num-fmt-percent,
#t-strikethrough,
#t-text-rotation,
#t-zoom,
#t-undo,
#t-redo,
#t-print,
#t-zoom-separator{
    display: none;
}
.docs-material #docs-toolbar-wrapper,
.docs-material #docs-equationtoolbar {
    padding: 0 4px 0 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another one version of CSS suitable for me, maybe for someone else.

[image: final menu]

```
#t-num-fmt-currency,
#t-num-fmt-percent,
#t-num-fmt-decimal-decrease,
#t-num-fmt-decimal-increase,
#t-num-fmt-other,
#docs-font-family,
#docs-font-size,
#t-text-rotation,
#t-cell-color-separator,
#t-docs-font-family-separator,
#t-docs-font-size-separator,
#t-bold-separator,
#t-num-fmt-currency-separator,
#t-merge-button,
#t-merge-menu,
#t-align-separator,
#t-moreButton,
#t-docs-toolbar-wrapper,
#t-viewModeButton,
#t-align,
#t-valign,
#t-textwrap,
#t-insert-doco,
#t-insert-chart,
#inputToolsSeparator,
#inputToolsToggleButton,
#t-zoom-separator{display: none;}
```